# Babel/Mocha: Mocha installed globally but describe() is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to run a test and I'm getting this error:

```
/dev/tests/counters.spec.js:12
describe('Work damn you!', function () {
^

ReferenceError: describe is not defined
```

Mocha is installed both globally and locally to the project. I'm not sure if I've got it right, but this is my test script:

```
"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register --require dev/tests/counters.spec.js"
```

Am I going anything that's plainly wrong? Any help would be welcome.

Comment: can we see the code from that file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration in `package.json`:

```
{
  // ...
  "test": "mocha dev/tests/counters.spec.js --compilers js:babel-register"
  // ...
}
```

The `--require` option is used to include modules like `should`, but not the unit test files. [See more](https://mochajs.org/#r---require-module-name) about this option.

Comment: it worked for me also just making sure the path to file goes right after the keyword `mocha`, because I had the --compliers before that and it didn't work either.