# TypeError: (0 , _chai.describe) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, babeljs

when I try to executing my react-tests with mocha, I got the following error:

```
/Users/niklaskiefer/Github/adal-fronted/test/CasesSpec.js:49
(0, _chai.describe)('Cases', function () {
                   ^

TypeError: (0 , _chai.describe) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (CasesSpec.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at loader (/Users/niklaskiefer/Github/adal-fronted/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/niklaskiefer/Github/adal-fronted/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /Users/niklaskiefer/Github/adal-fronted/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:220:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/niklaskiefer/Github/adal-fronted/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:217:14)
```

The test is located in test/CasesSpec:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'
import CaseActions from 'actions/CaseActions'
import CaseStore from 'stores/CaseStore'
import FilterStore from 'stores/FilterStore'
import { expect, it, before, describe } from 'chai'
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import Globals from 'config/globals'
import moment from 'moment'

var TestCases = require('./config/TestCases.js')

describe('Cases', function () {
  before(function (done) {
    this.timeout(1000)

    // fetch all data here because
...
```

I use the following command to execute the tests with 'npm test'

```
NODE_PATH=./app mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register,css:test/config/css-compiler.js --recursive --require test/config/setup.js
```

css-compiler.js:

```
function donothing () {
  return null
}

require.extensions['.css'] = donothing
require.extensions['.less'] = donothing
require.extensions['.scss'] = donothing
```

setups.js:

```
// this handles setup of the fake DOM when the tests are
// run in Node

import jsdom from 'jsdom'

var FAKE_DOM_HTML = `
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
`

function setupFakeDOM () {
  if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
    // if the fake DOM has already been set up, or
    // if running in a real browser, do nothing
    return
  }

  // setup the fake DOM environment.
  //
  // Note that we use the synchronous jsdom.jsdom() API
  // instead of jsdom.env() because the 'document' and 'window'
  // objects must be available when React is require()-d for
  // the first time.
  //
  // If you want to do any async setup in your tests, use
  // the before() and beforeEach() hooks.
  global.document = jsdom.jsdom(FAKE_DOM_HTML)
  global.window = document.defaultView
  global.navigator = window.navigator
}

setupFakeDOM()
```

It works properly few weeks ago, the only thing we changed is the fact we use standardJS as new codestyle. We also updated babel-core from 6.10.4 to 6.11.4. I tried out this solution: [Babel/Mocha: Mocha installed globally but describe() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141800/babel-mocha-mocha-installed-globally-but-describe-is-not-defined) and remove '--require'. But this just leads to no tests are executed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`it`, `before` and `describe` are symbols that are automatically added to the global space by Mocha. So they are available in tests without having to import anything.

`chai` certainly has nothing to do with them. So:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
```